# Take only that content of a span that is of certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a span that is dynamically filled with content. When the content reaches the width of 500px, I need to read the content that is of 300px. 
The content can be one line or multiple lines.

Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried something? Any code to start with?

Comment: @jSang - Actually i was trying to do something with scrollWidth and all. But then that will help only when it gets calculated as the letters are typed. I have the text added in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grabbag.js](https://github.com/doodads/grabbag.js) library has a method just for this purpose*.

There is not much documentation, but there is a function in there called grabbag.measure.crop that you can use to crop a string to a given dimension. I've written a little [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MyW3/) that will demonstrate how to use the library, but the basics go like this:

```
var result = grabbag.measure.crop(inputString, 300 /* number of pixels */, ele);
```

Where ele is a DOM element to "steal" styling from. Result will contain a string that just barely fits under the number of pixels given.

Hope that helps.

- Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of the library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it also possible to trim multiple lines in one go using your code?

Comment: No, the algorithm does one string/line at a time. To do multiple, you would have to loop over and call .crop on all of them.

Comment: WORKS WONDERS! Thank you so much ...your post has saved me so much time and I am sure a lot of people are looking for this solution...I am new here ...but if in anyway we can promote a post do let me know ..:)
PS: DOM element is different from jQuery element $("selector")[0] is supposed to be the ele not just $("selector"). Latter won't work!

Comment: While I was still working with the script, I realised that the clipping pf text doesnt work fine for fontsize 120px, Arial. It returns  a longer string ..I had edited the code in you file..do let me know if you ohk with me posting the edit here ..

Comment: Oh for sure. It would be even cooler though if you submitted a patch in GitHub for it if you get the chance. P.S. I am glad that you are finding the functionality useful.